# Master page of master page

Tags: asp.net-webforms

Есть старый сайт, написанный на `VB.NET` `ASP.NET WebForms`. Создано кучу страниц, которые ссылаются на одну мастер пейджу. Поставлена задача редизайна хидера и меню, но так же требуется держать старый дизайн.

Как это выглядит сейчас:

```
          +----------------------+
      +-->|      Master page     |<---------------+
      |   +----------------------+                |
      |                    ^                      |
      |                    |                      |
      +                    +                      |
  +-------------+   +---------------+             +
  |   Page      |   |    Page       |    ...A lot of pages...
  +-------------+   +---------------+
```

Дабы не ковырять **все страницы** решил попробовать сделать две дополнительные мастер пейджи, а текущую сделать "переключателем" между новыми:

```
+--------------------+ +-----------------------+
|     New master     | |       Old master      |
+--------------------+ +-----------------------+
          ^                         ^
          |                         |
          +-----------+-------------+
                      |
                      +
         +----------------------+
     +-->|      Master page     |<---------------+
     |   +----------------------+                |
     |                    ^                      |
     |                    |                      |
     +                    +                      |
 +-------------+   +---------------+             +
 |   Page      |   |    Page       |    ...A lot of pages...
 +-------------+   +---------------+
```

Но этот вариант не срабатывает из-за работы страницы с мастер пейджой. Вываливается эсепшны типа:

> Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'ContentPlaceHolder_Head' in the master page '...', verify content control's ContentPlaceHolderID attribute in the content page.

Т.к. эти айдишники содержатся не в `Master page`, который прикручен к страницам, а в `New master` и `Old master`, которые прикручиваются динамически в `Master page`.

Прошу совета как избежать перелопачивание всех страниц (вроде как на самой странице динамически подставлять мастер пейджу проблем не вызывае). Мержить два варианта дизайна в одну мастер пейджу не рассматриваю.

Comment: Отличный вопрос и с точки зрения практики реализуем. Если брать стандартный проект asp.net'а. Там есть сразу 2 master-page: Site.Master и Site.Mobile.Master. Они переключаются между собой с помощью ViewSwitcher.ascx. Единственное, экспериментировал на своём сайте. С мобильной версии сайт на полную переключается отлично, а вот наоборот не работает. Эту вещь можно и под ваши потребности приспособить... Своего рода получите переключатель между одной версией сайта и другой

Comment: @EgorTrutnev благодарю за ответ, а можете приложить какую-нибудь линку? Видел кучу примеров и во всех сменялась мастер пейджа на странице...

Comment: Я без проблем могу приложить хоть весь код. Но, так как переключаться с мобильной версии у меня получается, а вот наоборот - нет, выходит, что это не работает. Я уже давно собираюсь задать вопрос по данной проблеме. Возможно, как раз сейчас это и стоит сделать. Может кто и подскажет.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev буду признателен. Отпишитесь по окончании пожалуйста.